# Cannot push to Github after deploying app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, heroku

I'm using Github to deploy a Rails app to Heroku. I followed the steps in the Heroku guide and after pushing the app from my local machine I went to the Heroku console and linked my Github repo to the Heroku app. The app has been deployed to Heroku but isn't working, so I need to add something.

Because I deployed my app to Heroku, I now have both a a Github remote and a Heroku remote, which is to be expected. However, now when I try to commit my changes, I get this message:

```
error: 'heroku-app-name/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

Most of the answers I've seen to this are about new repos or other situations that don't apply to me. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Could you please indicate the commands you are using to commit the changes?

Comment: The error shows up as soon as I type `git add -A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote -v > git_rem_backup.txt
rm -rf .git
git init
git add -A .
git commit -m "first"
git remote add origin <data from git_rem_backup.txt>
git push origin master -f
```